# catoptions/menukeys packages compilation error

Tags: errors, menukeys

Before an update of TeXLive distribution, I used without problem the `menukeys` package. Since the update (a couple of days), the results are correct (PDF) but the following compilation error occurs (PDFLaTeX and LuaLaTeX):

```
 ! Extra \endgroup.
\document ->\endgroup 
    \let \BeforeStartOfDocument \@firstofone \cpt@beforestartdoc \let \BeforeStartOfDocument \@notprerr \gundefcs \cpt@beforestartdoc \gdef \cpt@docstarted {}\begingroup \UseOneTimeHook {begindocument/before}\@kernel@after@begindocum...
l.11 \begin{document}
```

Tracing back to the error with a MWE, it seems that the `catoptions` package induces the issue. The fact that this package has not been updated for several years is disturbing...

From where this issue may be coming from ?

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{menukeys}% Compilation error
\usepackage{catoptions}% Same compilation error

\begin{document}

\section{Menukeys test}

Where is the issue ? %\menu{File>New File}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `catoptions` is broken in the new LaTeX kernel because it does some heavy patching of internal commands.  The author was already contacted, but no response so far

Comment: the `menukeys` author has been notified some time ago too, and there is also an issue in the github: https://github.com/tweh/menukeys/issues/59

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and useful remarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the latest version of `menukeys` everything should work out as intended. Since 2020-10-31 (v1.6) `menukeys` no longer requires the `catoptions` package and therefore is again compatible with LaTeX2e.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{menukeys}% no compilation error

\begin{document}

\section{Menukeys test}

There is no issue! \menu{File>New File}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, you're right. I have noticed the new version which works fine now, but I did not dare to answer since the question was old fashioned: nevertheless, accepted answer for you!

Comment: @ejazz good to hear that your problem was already resolved by the update! I just thought it might be a good idea to "document" this here for future visitors (and possibly you, if you didn't notice until now).

Comment: You're right again. It's better like that.

Answer (score 3):

`catoptions` is incompatible with a lot of latex code and finally does not work at all in the current latex release. Until it is updated you can roll back the changes as follows

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{menukeys}% Compilation error
\usepackage{catoptions}% Same compilation error

\begin{document}

\section{Menukeys test}

Where is the issue ? %\menu{File>New File}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. Your solution works for `catoptions` but not for `menukeys` where the incompatibility seems to be deported to the `xstring` package.

Comment: @ejazz the xstring error is an error in the rollback code, that should be corrected.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oh you mean uncomment that menu command?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no simply using the package (it loads xparse and then everything explodes because of issue 406 I just opened)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer so I see and unfortunately you can't roll back further to 2019 and really remove expl3...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: As pointed out by ejazz, the below is merely a workaround.

I reverted with `tlmgr` by doing

```
$ tlmgr restore latex
Available backups for latex: 53958 (2020-10-08 13:20)
$ tlmgr restore latex 53958
```

and now I can compile documents using `menukeys` again without any error.

Comment: Thank you for the temporary workaround. The aim stays to have an updated distribution that works with `menukeys` too.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I edited the answer accordingly.