# zref-pagelayout/zref-abspos packages compilation error

Tags: errors, compilation-error, zref

Before a recent update of TeXLive distribution, a personal package dependant of several official packages worked fine. Since the update, the following compilation error occurs:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\Z@C@outputboxwd ->\AtBeginShipoutBoxWidth 
                                       
l.50 \end{document}
             
! Undefined control sequence.
\Z@C@outputboxht ->\AtBeginShipoutBoxHeight 
                                        
l.50 \end{document}
             
! Undefined control sequence.
\Z@C@outputboxdp ->\AtBeginShipoutBoxDepth 
                                       
l.50 \end{document}
```

Discarding all the correct package uploads, I noticed that the `zref-pagelayout` package, just loading it, leads to this compilation error.

Because the issue had not occurred before the update (in particular the new LaTeX kernel), is this error related to and of the same order that the question posted yesterday?
[catoptions/menukeys packages compilation error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565937/catoptions-menukeys-packages-compilation-error)

Is a workaround possible?

*MWE*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
%\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\usepackage{pgfkeys}
%\usepackage{ifthen}
%\usepackage{letltxmacro}
%\usepackage{ifplatform}
%\usepackage{shellesc}
%\usepackage{calc}
%\usepackage{filecontentsdef}
%\usepackage{catchfile}
%\usepackage{pdfbase}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, calc, chains, fit, positioning, shapes, shadings}
%\usepackage{tcolorbox}
%\tcbuselibrary{breakable, fitting, raster, skins, theorems, xparse, hooks}
%\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%\usepackage{ocgbase}
%\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
%\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
%\usepackage{linegoal}
%\usepackage{marginnote}
%\usepackage{framed}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
%\usepackage{atbegshi}
%\usepackage{zref-base}
%\usepackage{zref-savepos}
%\usepackage{zref-thepage}
%\usepackage{iftex}
%\usepackage{atveryend}
%\usepackage{zref-abspos}% Compilation error (loads zref-pagelayout)
\usepackage{zref-pagelayout}% Compilation error
%\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

\section{Test}

Where is the issue? From an incompatibility with the new LaTeX kernel (2020-10-01)?

\end{document}
```

Comment: I will fix it in the afternoon. Please open a bug report at the zref-github if possible.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks a lot for your reactivity

Comment: I actually had prepared it for the new latex already in june, I only forgot to upload it ;-(

Comment: I uploaded to ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Really impressive dynamics! It works like a charm. Thanks again.