# Problem with seminar style in miktex (20.11)

Tags: miktex, installing, seminar

After installing the latest miktex (20.11) on my new laptop, I tried to compile the following simple
presentation in seminar style:

```
\documentclass[portrait]{seminar}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide*}
aaa
\end{slide*}
\end{document}
```

But I get the following error:

\document ->\endgroup
\the \before@document \begingroup \UseOneTimeHook

On another machine where I use Miktex 2.9.6670 it works just fine.

Writing simple articles and Beamer presentations works fine.

Can anybody please help me. Thanks in advance

I also tried to find old miktex version 2.9.6670, but I could not find it anywhere.
Andrej

Comment: Seminar is a very old class and not compatible with a new latex. Why are you using it instead of e.g. beamer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know, it is a very old class, but I have several presentations prepared in this way. For newer presentations I use beamer, but it would be a lot of work to update all this old presentations in seminar style to beamer. So I will be very thankful if there is a way to compile seminars presentations. Andrej

Comment: Contact the maintainer and ask if he is willing to update the class to make it compatible again https://ctan.org/pkg/seminar (he should already know about the incompatibility)

Comment: Thanks. I did. I will see if he (Herbert Voß) will answer. BTW is it possible to get Miktex 2.9.6670 complete installation anywhere?

Comment: You can also try to roll back to an older latex with latexrelease https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565938/2388

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Anybody knows if it is possible to get Miktex 2.9.6670 complete installation anywhere? Or some other version like this?

Comment: it works for me with your small example, I tried. You can get older texlive, but with miktex it is not possible to rollback. overleaf allows to switch to older texlive too (and it hasn't the new format yet anyway) so you could try to compile there.

Comment: Compiling givesthe error: various corrections for the Seminar document class
added since seminar.bug and few add-ons for overlays
(Version 2.3 of <2014/05/12> (DG, hv))
) (C:\Viewers\MiKTeX\tex/latex/fancyvrb\hcolor.sty
`hcolor' v1.4, 1998/03/19 (Denis Girou)
! LaTeX Error: Command \FvrbEx@ColoredBox undefined.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                                                                                
l.21 \renewcommand\FvrbEx@ColoredBox
                                    [3]{%

Comment: well as I wrote: the example in my answers works for me.Tested on a current, up-to-date miktex. Don't expect me to guess what you added to your document to get  errors from hcolor and fancyvrb..

Comment: Thanks for another answer. The strange fact is that I did not add anything, I just tried to compile the same simple test file with \RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease} at the top. Why it looks to hcolor and fancyvrb is a miracle to me.

Comment: show the complete log-file when compiling my example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seminar` patches `\document` in a way that is not compatible with a LaTeX 2020-10-01 and the new hooks the format implemented (the maintainer has been notified some months ago about the upcomming problem).

As a work-around you can rollback to an older latex with `latexrelease`:

```
\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}
\documentclass[portrait]{seminar}
\begin{document}
\begin{slide*}
aaa
\end{slide*}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that this doesn't work with every package: if a new version of a package requires a feature of the new format it can fail or error if you rollback.

Comment: After restarting the computer and refreshing the file name database the example tex file with addition "\RequirePackage[2020-02-02]{latexrelease}" at the top compiles without any problem, Even more: now, with this addition, I can compile all my old presentations. Dear Ulrike: THANKS A LOT. You saved a lot of work and time to me. I really appreciate your help. The problem solved.

Comment: @AndrejMrvar as a warning: the package will probably get the status unmaintained and be moved to obsolet. That means texsystem will not longer install it.